# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k\cos (k x)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, fourier-series

My intent is to find an expression for the following summation,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\cos (k x).$$
We know that (cfr. *Sines and Cosines of Angles in Arithmetic Progression* by M. P. Knapp)
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos (k x)
=
\frac{\sin(nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)} \cos\left(\frac{(n-1)x}{2}\right)
$$
and I was wondering if something similar can be found if there is a and additional $k$-term in the summation.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's the derivative of the sum over $k$ of $\sin(kx)$, which can be computed similarly to your identity (creatively telescoping, using complex exponentials, etc.)

Comment: Yes, your comment has led me to the sought answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Using the above suggestion from User Simply Beautiful Art, that is, by writing the expression as a derivative of a sine function, we finally get:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \cos (kx)
&= 
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{d}{dx} \sin{kx} \\
&=
\frac{d}{dx} 
\left(\frac{\sin(kx/2)}{sin(x/2)} \sin\left(\frac{n-1}2 x\right)\right) \\
&=
\frac 1 2 \left(k \frac{\cos(kx/2)}{\sin{x/2}}-\frac{\sin(kx/2)}{\sin^2(x/2)} \cos(x/2)\right)\sin\left( \frac {n-1} 2 x\right) \\
&+
\frac{n-1}2 \frac{\sin(kx/2)}{\sin(x/2)} \cos\left(\frac{n-1}2 x\right)
\end{align} 
where in the second row we use again the formula from the reference given in the opening post. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: This is wrong, the result can't depend on $k$

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Step 1: $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{ikx}$ is a geometric sum. Write down its value. Step 2: differentiate w.r.t. $x$. Step 3: divide by $i$. Step 4: take real part on both sides.

Comment: Why divide by $i$ and then take the real part instead of simply taking the imaginary part?

Comment: Fine. No big deal.